# css,js,img folders not available for subdomain pointing to subfolder

Tags: html, subdomain, subdirectory

I created a subdomain for my site

```
subdomain.example.com
```

I then pointed it to a subdirectory inside the /public_html folder on the server, where i created an `index.html` file.
I referenced all assets in the html with `../img/`, `../css/`, `../js/` paths, but the page is having none of it. The `index.html` loads but all referenced files are shown as `404` in chrome.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "**I then** pointed it to a subdirectory" - Did you not point the subdomain to the subdirectory as part of the subdomain creation?

Comment: Yes. The subdomain is pointed to the subdirectory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I referenced all assets in the html with `../img/`, `../css/`, `../js/` paths.

These are client-side URL-paths; not server-side filesystem-paths. If the browser is currently at `https://subdomain.example.com/` then a URL such as `../img/myimage.jpg` cannot be resolved as intended from a client-side request. Since the browser cannot "go up" another directory (or rather URL path-segment) level - since it is already at the document root - it will most probably be resolved as `https://subdomain.example.com/img/myimage.jpg` - which presumably fails (404).

The same as typing `https://subdomain.example.com/../img/myimage.jpg` directly in the browser. The `../` path segment needs to be resolved by the *browser* before the request can be made.

You are probably better off not using *relative* URL-paths during development (unless you have specific requirements). Use a root-relative URL-path (starting with a slash) or absolute URL (with scheme + hostname) instead.

You need to rethink your directory structure. What exactly are you trying to achieve? A common repository for all assets or a way to reference assets on the main domain, without explicitly specifying an absolute URL.

There are various workarounds:

- Use absolute URL-paths to your main domain. eg.
  `https://example.com/img/myimage.jpg`
- Point the subdomain at the same root directory as your main domain and use a root-relative URL-path. eg.
  `/img/myimage.jpg`.
- Point the subdomain at the same root directory as the main domain and use mod_rewrite to internally rewrite requests for *pages* to the subdirectory (so the subdirectory is hidden from the URL). But all (or *some*?) static assets to be served from the parent directory (and are not rewritten)? Reference assets using a root-relative URL-path, relative to the main domain. (Or specify a *prefix* and make the rewrite conditional?) Although this method is naturally far more complex and requires knowledge of conditional URL-rewriting (probably best avoided).
- etc.

Comment: thank you so much for explaining. That really helps.
I'll try workaround 1 tonight.
workaround 2: If I do it that way, how would the subdomain automatically load the index.html file in the subdirectory?
workaround 3: would that be done in the .htaccess file?

Comment: "workaround 2: If I do it that way, how would the subdomain automatically load the index.html file in the subdirectory?" - Well, it starts getting more complex. If the subdomain points to the document root of the main domain then you wouldn't necessarily have a subdirectory. You could have `index.html` and `index-subdomain.html` and conditionally rewrite the request for the _root_ based on the requested host header. Or, keep the subdirectory and again, conditionally rewrite the request (although this is really #3).

Comment: Yes, any URL-rewriting will require mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` (or the server config). If you have access to the server-config then you can also create symlinks (essentially "duplicating" the files) or create an `Alias`. Many possibilities depending on the specific requirements, but #1 is by far the simplest. But note that you need to be careful of any relative URL-paths in your CSS and JS files - if they are being used from two different URL locations - as you are naturally changing the base URL from which the relative URLs are _relative_ to.

Comment: I have a follow up question. I am dealing with my website only once a year, so relevant knowledge fades away really quickly.
I now want to serve a localized language version of the website `www.website.com` on `www.website.com/en`. 
I though I solved my previous problem with your help by placing an .htaccess file with a rewrite rule in the new folder. So, I copied the .htaccess file from the subdomain (from last November) in a newly created /en folder on my server. I also placed the translated index.html in that new /en folder.

Comment: But `www.website.com/en` just serves me the raw HTML without images or CSS.
I am sure it's the same workaround as last time, but I cannot figure this out..